# Joining faces in a model

Tags: modeling, faces, 3d-printing

I recently started dabbling into 3d printing. I extracted a model from a old game, but I noticed that the faces of the model are not 'glued' to each other, they are basically standalone faces near other faces to make the model, how can I make the model a solid or how to join 2 faces to do it to the whole model manually?

Answer (score 1):

Select all vertices, right click and then select merge, merge by distance, which should do just as you want.

[image]

Hope this helped!

Comment: I'll try that! Thank you!